# Get the current time in a given time range

Tags: android

So I have a time range example:

```
2016-09-26T12:00:00.000+08:00 / 2016-09-27T11:59:00.000+08:00
```

Assuming the current time is `2016-09-29T06:00:00.000+08:00`

So what I want is to get which of dates on the said time range (2016-09-26 or 2016-09-27) the 06:00AM falls...

I tried using joda's Interval class but I can't figure out how to make it work. any suggestion is appreciated.

sample expected outputs:

- 06:00AM => 2016-09-27
- 06:00PM => 2016-09-26
- 03:00AM => 2016-09-27
- 03:00PM => 2016-09-26

Comment: use simpledataformate!!

Comment: what is simpledataformate? never heard of that. are you referring to SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: What did you try with Joda time? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I already got it working using Joda.DateTime... see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss");

    String strEndDate = "2016-09-27T11:59:00.000+0800";
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:MM:ss.SSSZ");

    Date endDate = null;

    try {
        endDate = fmt.parse(strEndDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    Date currDate = new Date();  // you can set your date and time here

    while(currDate.after(endDate)){
        currDate.setTime(currDate.getTime()-(24*60*60*1000));
    }

    String result = fmt.format(currDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way that works for me

```
DateTime beginTime = getStartTime();
DateTime withTimeNow = beginTime.withTime(LocalTime.now())

LocalDate result = withTimeNow.isBefore(beginTime)? beginTime.toLocalDate().plusDays(1) : beginTime.toLocalDate();
```

I'm not sure if it's efficient but it does what I need.